# prettyphoto inline javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm using prettyphoto with inline content, the issue I'm having is that the javascript doesn't seem to function within prettyphoto when the item is enlarged.

I've tried placing the javascript within the actual tag which is called and opened. Is there a method of saying when an item is selected this javascript should run within pretty photo.

I'm simply using

```
<a href="#item" rel="pop"></a><div id="item">contents</div>
```